# Why does calling get of a bound value in the binding throw a stackoverflow error

Tags: java, javafx, binding, stack-overflow, bind

This code throws a stackoverflowerror in a label binding when getting the value of the label being bound. I expect the label to be "test" initially then on the first press "test pressed" then "test pressed pressed" and so on. However reading the value throws a stackoverflowerror because calling the getText() method triggers the binding. I expect only button press events to trigger the binding.

Note: I've commented out the code which causes the error and added another button to better show what I'm confused about.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label l = new Label("test");
        Button b = new Button("press me");

        l.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->{
            System.out.println("changing label text");
            return "ok";
            //return l.getText() + " pressed"; //Causes a stackoverflow error
        },b.pressedProperty()));

        Button b2 = new Button("press me 2");
        b2.pressedProperty().addListener((o) -> {
            l.getText(); //Why does this not triggger the binding?
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(l,b,b2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Binding test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My objective here is to have a binding which, on a certain condition, does not change the text. The logic in the Callable Lambda is something like:

```
if(condition){
    return "ok";
}else{
    return l.getText(); //if the condition is not met then use the current value.
}
```

I know I can use a listener on the pressed property and then set the text label that way, so I have a solution but I would like to know why the above is happening.

Comment: Your binding expresses the rule that the label's text is the label's text concatenated with `" pressed"`... it's infinitely recursive

Comment: @James_D I understand that the logic recurs, but the condition that triggers the recursion should be the observable value that Bindings.createStringBinding() is binding to (b.pressed), not the value of the label.

Comment: But what is the value of the binding? Basically, when the value of the binding is computed, you have to evaluate `label.getText()`, which looks at the value of the label's `textProperty()`. That value hasn't been set since it was invalidated (because it's still in the process of being set), so to get the value, the binding has to be computed.

Comment: The value of the binding should be l.getText() + "pressed". I expect the value to be bound to the pressed property, not to itself.

Comment: Yeah, but what does `l.getText()` return?

Comment: @James_D The value of the label's text property... I'm not understanding why this is triggering the binding.

Comment: The value of the label's text property is defined by the binding (because it's bound to it...)

Comment: @James_D I've updated my question to show what I'm confused about. When b2 is pressed the Callable is not run, why would it be called only when l.getText() is called within the callable?

Comment: In this case, the text hasn't changed (because the property to which the binding is bound - `b.pressedProperty()` hasn't changed), so there is no need to recompute it. `l.getText()` just returns the cached value.

Comment: I see that, I would understand if the b.pressedProperty was edited why the binding would recur. I'm not really following why the getText function would cause the recursion... It should not trigger and update in the binding (or at least I don't expect it to).

Comment: It doesn't "trigger" it: it just has to call your `computeValue()` method in order to get the result of `computeValue()`. The value of the binding is defined by the method you provide, but the method you provide *depends on the value of the binding*. Added an answer which makes it explicit.

Comment: "it just has to call your `computeValue()` method in order to get the result of `computeValue()`" Do you mean something else for the second `computeValue()`? I see the answer, I think it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: By `computeValue()` I just mean the anonymous method (lambda expression) you provided to `createStringBinding(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just semantically, your binding expresses the rule that the text of the label is the text of the label concatenated with `" pressed"`. Clearly this is saying that the label's text depends on the label's text, so it's recursive.

I don't think this is the rule you want to impose anyway. I think you want the 
rule to be "the label's text is `"test"` if the button is not pressed, and `"test pressed"` if the button is pressed. (Right now your binding is told to recompute if the button's `pressed` property changes, but the value doesn't actually depend on that property.)

Technically what's happening is something along the following lines:

```
public class Label {

    private final StringProperty textProperty = new SimpleStringProperty() ;

    public String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    // ...
}
```

and

```
public class SimpleStringProperty {

    private StringBinding binding ;
    private boolean bound ;
    private String value ;

    // ...

    public String get() {
        if (bound) {
            value = binding.get();
        }
        return value ;
    }

    public void bind(StringBinding binding) {
        bound = true ;
        this.binding = binding ;
        value = binding.get();
    }
}
```

Finally, string binding has logic along the following lines:

```
public abstract class StringBinding {

    private boolean valid = false;
    private String value ;

    protected void bind(ObservableStringValue dependency) {
        dependency.addListener(o -> invalidate());
    }

    private void invalidate() {
        valid = false ;
        // notify invalidation listeners...
    }

    public String get() {
        if (!valid) {
            value = computeValue();
            valid = true ;
        }
        return value ;
    }

    public abstract String computeValue();
}
```

And in your example, the implementation of `computeValue()` invokes the label's `getText()` method.

So when you create the binding, the value of the label's text property is set from the value of the binding. The binding isn't valid (because it hasn't been computed yet), so it is computed via the method you provide. That method invokes `label.getText()`, which gets the value from the property. Because the property is bound, it check the binding, which still isn't valid (because the computation of its value hasn't been completed), so it computes its value, which invokes `label.getText()`...

So you probably want something like:

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    if (b.isPressed()) {
         return "test pressed";
    } else {
         return "test";
    }
}, b.pressedProperty());
```

If you want the underlying string to be able to be changed, you need to create a new property for it:

```
StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty("test");
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    if (b.isPressed)() {
        return text.get() + " pressed" ;
    } else {
        return text.get();
    }
}, text, b.pressedProperty());
```

or, equivalently

```
label.textProperty().bind(text.concat(
    Bindings.when(b.pressedProperty())
    .then(" pressed")
    .otherwise("")));
```

Comment: The rule I want to impose is: `If(condition){setValue}else{//do not change text}.` I did the 'not change text' logic by calling the getValue(). This is a great explanation of why it does not work, thanks.

Comment: @BlakeParmeter what you're describing there sounds more like a listener - because it's performing an action (`setValue(...)`) than a binding (which just evaluates to something).